# Files reduce to zero byte(empty) whenever I paste it or save it in a particular partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

In a dual boot system, I have a directory which can be access by Ubuntu also. Folders can be created, files can be renamed and files can be copied from, but whenever I try to paste or save any file in this directory, it is saved/pasted as an empty file (0 byte). Can I know its solution please?

Please see the size of image on both side in photo (the right one is the pasted one).

[image: Please see the size of image on both side in photo(right one is pasted one).]